# image of a normal subgroup under a non-surjective group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that ${\phi}:G\rightarrow{G'}$ is *not* a surjective group homomorphism. Does there always exist a normal subgroup of $G$ whose image ${\phi}(G)$ fails to be normal in $G'$?

Comment: Not always, no.  What if $G'$ is abelian?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not necessarily such a subgroup. For instance, if the image of all of $G$ is contained in the center of $G'$ ($G'$ being abelian, or $\phi$ being trivial, are two cases where this happens), then $\phi(H)$ will be normal in $G'$ for any subgroup $H\subseteq G$.

Comment: So, Arthur, is that the condition then? I mean is the following assertion true? Assume that ${\phi}:G\rightarrow{G'}$ is a group homomorphism such that ${\phi}(G)\not\subset{Z(G')}$ where $Z(G')$ is the center of $G'$. Does there always exist a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that ${\phi}(N)$ is not a normal subgroup of $G'$?

Comment: An interesting example is the dihedral group of order 8 (the symmetries of the square). This seems to bear out your claim.